# Typescript .d.ts declare object literal with optional keys in function signature?

Tags: typescript

I have a `.d.ts` file like:

```js
declare function myfunc(): {
  something: (err, { req, res, errorInfo, query, pathname, extra }?) => void;
};
```

So it declares a function that has two args, the second being an optional "options" object.

But I want also to make the *keys* of the options object optional, i.e. so I can legally pass a partial object as the second arg.

What is the syntax for that?

Comment: At this point, declaring it as a separate type and then using that seems the least verbose option.

Comment: @Etheryte so declare a type or interface, then have a named second arg like `options: OptionsType` ?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that. You can of course do the same thing inline, but this declaration is already growing pretty long as is.

Comment: @Etheryte thanks, feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the second argument a name too. Then you can make it optional.

```
declare function myfunc(): {
  something: (err: any, arg2?: { req: any, res: any }) => void;
};
```

Comment: it's already optional, I want optional keys within the second arg

Comment: so what is stopping you from making them optional too? https://tsplay.dev/wQ8KnW

Comment: I could not find the syntax (which is why I asked for it in the question)... I tried `{ req?, res?, errorInfo?, query?, pathname?, extra? }` but it's not valid

Comment: see the playground link above